# Question on Polynomial function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Suppose $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ having integer coefficients and $13 < a < b < c$ are integers such that $f(13) = f(a) = 13$ and $f(b) = f(c) = 19$: Determine the possible values of $a,b,c$.

Could someone give me an idea what type of $f(x)$ I should assume?  The term polynomial is too general and further, four values are given and I tried a cubic polynomial but was not successful.

Comment: Learn about the (Lagrange interpolation polynomial)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is Bezout theorem: If $f$ is integral polynomial, and $A,B$ are integers, then: $ A-B $ divides $f(A) - f(B)$.

In your example, you find that $6 = 19 - 16$ has to be divisible by $b-a,b-13,c-a,c-13$. This leaves very few possibilities: for starters, $b,c$ are among the numbers $13+1,13+2,13+3,13+6$. For each choice, just take a look if you can find suitable $a$. This is clearly impossible for $b=14$, and also for $c=19$ (it would imply $a \geq 16$, but then there is no choice for $b$). Thus, you can only take $b=15,\ c=16$, and then indeed $a = 14$ is a legitimate choice.

Now, just try to find a polynomial though these points.

Comment: Thanks, it took some time to go through your solution but makes sense.  Thanks